# JavaScript date/time/text format

Tags: javascript

I have some deprecated JavaScript that works, but uses `document.write()`, and would like to update it. I have tried `document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = d.toString();`, but that doesn't work. I've searched thoroughly on the web but had no luck. I have included the JavaScript time script. Your help would be appreciated. Rich.

```js
var d = new Date();
var dateText = "";
var dayValue = d.getDay();
if (dayValue === 0)
  dateText += "Sunday";
else if (dayValue === 1)
  dateText += "Monday";
else if (dayValue === 2)
  dateText += "Tuesday";
else if (dayValue === 3)
  dateText += "Wednesday";
else if (dayValue === 4)
  dateText += "Thursday";
else if (dayValue === 5)
  dateText += "Friday";
else if (dayValue === 6)
  dateText += "Saturday";

var monthValue = d.getMonth();
dateText += " ";
if (monthValue === 0)
  dateText += "January";
if (monthValue === 1)
  dateText += "February";
if (monthValue === 2)
  dateText += "March";
if (monthValue === 3)
  dateText += "April";
if (monthValue === 4)
  dateText += "May";
if (monthValue === 5)
  dateText += "June";
if (monthValue === 6)
  dateText += "July";
if (monthValue === 7)
  dateText += "August";
if (monthValue === 8)
  dateText += "September";
if (monthValue === 9)
  dateText += "October";
if (monthValue === 10)
  dateText += "November";
if (monthValue === 11)
  dateText += "December";

if (navigator.appName.indexOf('Microsoft') !== -1)
  dateText += " " + d.getDate() + ", " + (1900 + d.getYear());
else if (navigator.appName.indexOf('Netscape') !== -1)
  dateText += " " + d.getDate() + ", " + (1900 + d.getYear());
else if (navigator.appName.indexOf('Opera') !== -1)
  dateText += " " + d.getDate() + ", " + (1900 + d.getYear());

var minuteValue = d.getMinutes();
if (minuteValue < 10)
  minuteValue = "0" + minuteValue

var hourValue = d.getHours();
if (hourValue < 12) {
  greeting = "Good morning!";
  var timeText = " at " + hourValue + ":" + minuteValue +
    " AM. &nbsp;Welcome!";

} else if (hourValue === 12) {
  var greeting = "Good afternoon!";
  timeText = " at " + hourValue + ":" + minuteValue +
    " PM. &nbsp;Welcome! ";
} else if (hourValue < 17) {
  greeting = "Good afternoon!";
  timeText = " at " + (hourValue - 12) + ":" + minuteValue +
    " PM. &nbsp;Welcome! ";
} else {
  greeting = "Good evening!";
  timeText = " at " + (hourValue - 12) + ":" + minuteValue +
    " PM. &nbsp;Welcome! ";
}
document.open();
document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = d.toString();
// ORIGINAL - document.write(greeting + " It's " + dateText + timeText);
```

Comment: This is not a refactor-my-code site.

Comment: And have you actually got an element on the page with an ID of greeting?

Comment: Just use https://momentjs.com/docs/ for Datetime handling

Answer (score -1):

All you are missing is an element on the page that has the ID `greeting`, which is required for **[`document.getElementById("greeting")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)**. You can't set the **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** of an element that doesn't exist in the DOM!

You also don't need `document.open()`.

Here's a working example with a `greeting` element added:

```js
var d = new Date();
var dateText = "";
var dayValue = d.getDay();
if (dayValue === 0)
  dateText += "Sunday";
else if (dayValue === 1)
  dateText += "Monday";
else if (dayValue === 2)
  dateText += "Tuesday";
else if (dayValue === 3)
  dateText += "Wednesday";
else if (dayValue === 4)
  dateText += "Thursday";
else if (dayValue === 5)
  dateText += "Friday";
else if (dayValue === 6)
  dateText += "Saturday";

var monthValue = d.getMonth();
dateText += " ";
if (monthValue === 0)
  dateText += "January";
if (monthValue === 1)
  dateText += "February";
if (monthValue === 2)
  dateText += "March";
if (monthValue === 3)
  dateText += "April";
if (monthValue === 4)
  dateText += "May";
if (monthValue === 5)
  dateText += "June";
if (monthValue === 6)
  dateText += "July";
if (monthValue === 7)
  dateText += "August";
if (monthValue === 8)
  dateText += "September";
if (monthValue === 9)
  dateText += "October";
if (monthValue === 10)
  dateText += "November";
if (monthValue === 11)
  dateText += "December";

if (navigator.appName.indexOf('Microsoft') !== -1)
  dateText += " " + d.getDate() + ", " + (1900 + d.getYear());
else if (navigator.appName.indexOf('Netscape') !== -1)
  dateText += " " + d.getDate() + ", " + (1900 + d.getYear());
else if (navigator.appName.indexOf('Opera') !== -1)
  dateText += " " + d.getDate() + ", " + (1900 + d.getYear());

var minuteValue = d.getMinutes();
if (minuteValue < 10)
  minuteValue = "0" + minuteValue

var hourValue = d.getHours();
if (hourValue < 12) {
  greeting = "Good morning!";
  var timeText = " at " + hourValue + ":" + minuteValue +
    " AM. &nbsp;Welcome!";

} else if (hourValue === 12) {
  var greeting = "Good afternoon!";
  timeText = " at " + hourValue + ":" + minuteValue +
    " PM. &nbsp;Welcome! ";
} else if (hourValue < 17) {
  greeting = "Good afternoon!";
  timeText = " at " + (hourValue - 12) + ":" + minuteValue +
    " PM. &nbsp;Welcome! ";
} else {
  greeting = "Good evening!";
  timeText = " at " + (hourValue - 12) + ":" + minuteValue +
    " PM. &nbsp;Welcome! ";
}
document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = d.toString();
```

```html
<div id="greeting"></div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Gotta love StackOverflow; you provide the correct answer, though get down-voted due to people thinking the OP hasn't done enough research.